# How to open/close a URL via/ a script

Tags: url, automation

I was wondering whether there was a way to automate the opening of "`www.google.com"`, view the page for a set time (500 milliseconds), close the web page and then repeat the process multiple times. Headless solutions (those that do not involve the page physically opening up on the screen) is preferred.

So far, I have looked into `HtmlUnit` with `Java` but it doesn't work because some web pages use `javascript` and it does not work well with `javascript`.

I have tried Selenium with Java but I do not want the page to constantly open up on my screen (it is not a headless solution).

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

[Nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) might do the trick:

The following code should provide headless testing:

```
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: false});
```